# SpaCy custom NER training AttributeError: 'DocBin' object has no attribute 'to_disk'

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I want to train a custom NER model using spaCy v3 I prepared my train data and I used this script

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
        if span is None:
            pass
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

then it prints this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DocBin' object has no attribute 'to_disk'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are really using spaCy 3, in case you haven't :)

You can check this from the console by running `python -c "import spacy; print(spacy.__version__)"`

By issuing via command line `pip install spacy==3.0.6` in a python env, and then running in the python console

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

# omitting code for debugging purposes

db.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

you should get no errors.

Comment: Thank you in fact I found out that I'm not using the v3 even though I upgraded the version, I was working on google colab and I couldn't get the spacy v3 there so I tried anaconda Jupiter notebook after installing spacy v3 and it works this time

Comment: I see! However a `!pip install spacy==3.0.6` should fix it when run in a Google colab cell as well. Cheers!